# Find nested divs scrapy

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to get the text from a div that is nested.  Here is the code that I currently have:

```
sites = hxs.select('/html/body/div[@class="content"]/div[@class="container listing-page"]/div[@class="listing"]/div[@class="listing-heading"]/div[@class="price-container"]/div[@class="price"]')
```

But it is not returning a value.  Is my syntax wrong?  Essentially I just want the text out of  `<div class="price">`

Any ideas?

The URL is [here](http://www.ksl.com/index.php?sid=17403849&nid=651&ad=452978).

Comment: Can you post the URL that are you trying to scrape?

Comment: http://www.ksl.com/index.php?sid=17403849&nid=651&ad=452978

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The price is inside an iframe so you should scrape https://www.rentler.com/ksl/listing/index/?sid=17403849&nid=651&ad=452978

Once you request this url:

```
hxs.select('//div[@class="price"]/text()').extract()[0]
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I get the same results using the new URL.  Are you able to pull the data? @fasouto